# Azure Graph API : Error 403 Forbidden with Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an Azure AD B2C. Since Azure Active Directory has been migrated to new portal, I have a problem to read and write tenant users data with the Azure Graph API. Before, I had an application which was created from the old portal and which doesn't work now.

So, I created a new application from the new portal, as following :

- Open "Azure Active Directory" tab
- Open "App registrations"
- Click "New application registration"
- "Properties" tab with :

  > - Name : GraphApi
  > - App ID URI : https://myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/graphapi
  > - Home page URL : https://graph.windows.net/winbizdev.onmicrosoft.com
- "Reply URLs" tab with :

  > - https:// graph.windows.net/winbizdev.onmicrosoft.com
- "Required permissions" tab with :

  > - Windows Azure Active Directory -> Check 3 elements which don't require admin
- "Keys" tab with :

  > - CLIENT_SECRET which never expires

Here is now my C# code to access user data from Azure Graph API :

```
      _authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenant.onmicrosoft.com");
      _credential = new ClientCredential("<Application Client Guid>", "<Client secret which I created in "Keys" tab");
      var result = await _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", _credential);          
      var http = new HttpClient();
      var graphUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/myTenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/<My User Guid>?api-version=1.6";    
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), graphUrl);
      request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);      
      var response = await http.SendAsync(request);
      return response;
```

And I always obtain a 403 error Forbidden. The version of the assembly "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" is 3.13.8.99.

So, what is wrong in my configuration? What I have to do to read and write user tenant users data again with Azure Graph API?

Thanks for your help!

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are acquiring acess token using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) . That means you need add related **Application Permissions** in `Required permissions` blade .

All application permissions of azure ad graph api need admin consent . Please click `Grant Permissions` button(login with admin's account) after adding application permissions .

Comment: Thanks for your response and your help!
In my AD, I see only users which are "Member".
I try to create a user which is "Global admin", but I open his properties, this user is "Member".
So, I don't know how to have or create an admin for his AD which can grant perrmissions for all other users...
How can I do that?

Comment: can you change the directory role to `Global admin` ?  What is the directory role of your account ? If not `global admin` , please ask for company's IT support

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see in the right tab. I saw in the "Profile" tab and "User type" is "Member". But in the "Directory role", we retrieve global admins which was created from the old portal.

Last question: because the configuration has changed with the migration from the old to the new portal, do you know if other changes are planned? I ask this question because before this migration, we can access Graph API without problem and then, suddenly, nothing works and we had to change our configuration.

But now, all works again. So, thanks for your precious help!

Comment: Not sure where may cause the potential risk , if meeting problem , feel free to let me know  . Please [mark my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) , which will help others who meet same problem .